# all time data without setting facet.date.start to a random past date

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I use the following query to get time-series data of Posts.

```
q=*:*&facet=true&facet.date=created_at_d&start=0
&f.created_at_d.facet.date.start=2009-06-20T14:05:28Z
&f.created_at_d.facet.date.end=2011-07-05T14:05:28Z
&f.created_at_d.facet.date.gap=%2B3600SECONDS
&fq=type:Post&rows=0&f.created_at_d.facet.mincount=1
&facet.sort=count
```

Is there a way to get all time data without setting facet.date.start to a random past date(say 100 years)?.

```
All time data => from the created_at of the very first Post.
```

Comment: I'm busy searching the web for an answer to the same problem. Have you found one back then?

Comment: There is no way within Solr. We created $posts_first_created_at=Post.first.create_at to store the value during the rails initialization. That code gets run only once during the JVM (we use tomcat/jruby) boot up.

Answer (score 0):

It's a separate query for solr or your db to find that first date so probably easiest to get from the database.

```
Post.first(:order => 'created_at ASC').created_at.iso8601
```